# cursor factory parameters has no effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a database `class` like:

```
rlock = RLock()
class PostgresDB:
    host = Settings.DB_HOST
    name = Settings.DB_NAME
    username = Settings.DB_USERNAME
    pwd = Settings.DB_PWD

    def __init__(self):
        self.con = None

    def _create_connection(self):
        if self.con is None or self.con.closed:
            self.con = psycopg2.connect("host={h} dbname={n} user={u} password={p}".format(
                h=self.host, n=self.name, u=self.username, p=self.pwd,
                cursor_factory=RealDictCursor))

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def reading_cursor(self, sql, params=None):
        rlock.acquire()
        self._create_connection()
        try:
            cur = self.con.cursor()
            cur.execute(sql, params)
            yield cur
        except DatabaseError as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            yield Exception()
        finally:
            self.con.close()
        rlock.release()

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def writing_cursor(self, sql, params=None):
        rlock.acquire()
        self._create_connection()
        try:
            cur = self.con.cursor()
            cur.execute(sql, params)
            yield cur
            self.con.commit()
        except DatabaseError as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            yield Exception()

        finally:
            self.con.close()
            rlock.release()
```

Note that I am explicitly asking for `RealDictCursor`.
However, when any request is done, the result is a list of `tuples`, not `dicts`. I am not sure what I am missing?

Comment: I think it's your context stuff rather than psycopg2. Try `yield iter(cur)` instead of plain cur.

Comment: Try: `cur = self.con.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is incredibly stupid... If you look closely you will see I passed `cursor_factory` to `.format()` instead of passing it to `.connect()` ...